# java streams: Collect stream of Iterable<? extends String>

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm getting a compilation error on:

```
@Override
public Map<String, T> loadAll(Iterable<? extends String> keys) {
    return Stream.of(keys)
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), this::load));
}
```

The compiler message is:

> The method `collect(Collector<? super Iterable<capture#1-of ? extends String>,A,R>)` in the type `Stream<Iterable<capture#1-of ? extends String>>` is not applicable for the arguments (`Collector<String,capture#2-of ?,Map<Object,Reference>>`)

Any work around?

Comment: what do you think `Stream.of(keys)` returns?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you think that `Stream.of(keys)` will create a `Stream<String>`, but that is not the case. To create a `Stream` from an `Iterable`, you should use `StreamSupport#stream`:

```
public Map<String, T> loadAll(Iterable<? extends String> keys) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(keys.spliterator(), false)
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), this::load));
}
```

This assumes that your `load` method returns `T`.

Comment: Is there any jdk 11 more elegant way to achieve the same?